# PyPI bezier 0.8.0: Minimum number of points needed to plot a smooth bezier curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bezier

The function `bezier.curve.plot(num_pts, ...)` in **PyPI bezier 0.8.0** one can start using a low number of **num_pts** and increase it until one gets a perfectly smooth curve -- i.e. one that does not show the slightest sign of a polygon -- after which any increase of these points **will not improve the curve**.

Now, in the examples I dinf in the Web I usually see **num_pts=256**, which I find extremely high, since I have never met a case needing more than 80 points, considering the most complex curve I have plotted. And this is what I always use, until I find it is too little. So, I wonder if this is just a habit propagated among programmers or there's a real reason for it. Doesn't this produce a kind of overwork/overload/overtime to the process, esp. when plotting a lot of curves, as e.g. in an animation? And, coming back to my basic question, **is there a method with which one can find the minimum number of points needed to plot a smooth bezier curve?**

Comment: So, this is a trick question, because "is there a method with which one can find the minimum number of points needed to plot a smooth bezier curve?" is answered with "absolutely, it's curve-order-plus-one." However, is `bezier.curve.plot` written to perform true curve fitting as long as it has the minimal number of points required? Because if it isn't, writing your own curve abstractor requires surprisingly little code. To find a smooth quadratic, you just need three points. Smooth cubic: four, smooth quartic: five, etc. etc. (see https://pomax.github.io/BezierInfo-2/#curvefitting)

Comment: Thanks.

1) I think I explained well what I mean by "smooth" curve

2) Using dimension+1 points does not produce a curve but a polygon. And it's not what I am talking about.

3) Thanks for your ref. However, it's too scientific for me.

Comment: 1) you did, and that's why 2) no, I'm talking about Bezier curves, and then 3) it's high school maths. In order to fit a perfectly smooth nth order Bezier curve without too much guess work, n+1 points is sufficient. Now, whether that's what PyyPi's `bezier.curve.plot` will let you do is a completely _different_ question, so: do you want to know how to get a smooth curve, that you can then draw with any drawing library, or do you want to use `bezier.curve.plot` and even though there might be better solutions, you don't want them?

Comment: OK. Thanks @Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's mostly inertia -- copying legacy code.

This hearkens back to days in which the visual plot region was typically much larger, such as a full screen object.  "Smooth" is relative to the viewer's retina.  256 made a convenient block of memory to allocate and reclaim for the passed array of floats, saving some time for that part of the OS load.

When plotting smaller objects, such as a typical animation, you're quite right: lower numbers will give a curve that appears to be as smooth.  With the advent of vector-based machine operations and supporting parallel processing, the time difference isn't significant for most applications.  Coders for applications requiring high frame rates are cognizant of many real-time optimizations, and will catch this when it matters.

Comment: Thanks. Right, it's from "inertia" (I call it "bad habits" :). And your answer solves at least the Do-I-have-to-worry-about-it?  part. :)  An old-time programmer like me, though, grown up on code optimization code principles (thankgod I lived in that era! :)  always looks for "most efficient", "best use", etc.  But maybe this too is a "bad habit" afterall! :)